# How to Create a folder after path and file is validated?

Tags: c#, regex

While I'm creating a folder, the path contains some illegal characters.So I have removed it using Regex

```
folder = Regex.Replace(folder, @"[^\w\.@-]", "", 
                                RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
  if (!Directory.Exists(folder)
   {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);                    
    }
```

Now my folder path is free of illegal characters.But I'm not able to create a folder with the path after the removal of illegal characters.
May I know what should be done

Comment: Can you give me the path?

Comment: what do u mean by illegal characters?i think the return path is not correct..can you mention your path ?

Comment: E:\blog\ Intel Core i7-5960X Underwater: Can a Custom Loop Raise the Ceiling? It contains colon(:) n questionmark(?)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can check if the path is correct with this below code:

```
var invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars(path)
```

Check if the files is correct with this below code:

```
var invalidFileNameChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars(fileName)
```

If you want a regular expression that validates a folder path, then try this below code

```
folder = Regex.Replace(folder, @"^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*]+)+\\\\?$", 
                                RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

### Edit

**Create folder after it validates**

```
         var invalidPathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars(path)
         var invalidFileNameChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars(fileName)

         if(invalidPathChars ==True && invalidFileNameChars == True)
            {    
              // Folder creating code
            }
         else
            {
             //Show error message 
            }
```

### Update

Your if condition is wrong 
you need to check the conition for **folder** variable not a **folderpath** variable

try this code instead of your code

```
folder = Regex.Replace(folder, @"^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*]+)+\\\\?$", 
                                    RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
if (!Directory.Exists(folder)
   {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);                    
    }
```

**But i am not sure, what's your  valid variable name for the path and file name

Comment: I would like to create folder after it validates

Comment: I want to remove those invalid path chars and create that folder

Comment: try it `folder = Regex.Replace(folder, @"^([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[^<>:\"/\\\\|?*]+)+\\\\?$", "")`

Comment: It replaces the invalid chars but not creating when i'm using  Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);

Comment: There is no error message,but doesn't create a folder

Comment: please refresh the solution explorer to see new created folders, and also you need click the included files option for open excluded files.

Comment: check my updated question and I'm creating those folders in my local path

Comment: I'm checking with folder only, mistakenly kept folderpath.I was trying same as your code yet not working